# TextInputLayout doesn't show hint when focused if the hint was set programmatically

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm doing this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And then this:

```
mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
mEmailView.setHint("Email");
```

And the hint shows on the `EditText` but not above it when focused. I can set the hint on the `TextInputLayout` but then I get it at the same time as the hint inside `EditText`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `setHint()` on child EditText, you should call it on your `TextInputLayout` directly:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
textInputLayout.setHint("Email");
```

This should work out of the box without additional "hacks".

`TextInputLayout` does try to initialize its hint from an inner `EditText` hint, but it does this only upon creation and if it doesn't find it, it does nothing, so that's why you need to make it "try again" by calling `setHintEnabled()`...

I guess documentation should describe this nuance more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out, seems like a bug to me.

Basically I had to :

```
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mEmailView.setHint("Email");
    TextInputLayout textInputLayout= (TextInputLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
    textInputLayout.setHintEnabled(false);
    textInputLayout.setHintEnabled(true);
```